# location search autocomplete and select city and state

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

```
       <script>
            function initMap() {

                var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                    infowindow.close();
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }
                    //Location details
                    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                        if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'postal_code') {
                            document.getElementById('postal_code').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                        }
                        if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'country') {
                            document.getElementById('country').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                        }
                        if (place.address_components[i].types[0] === 'cities') {
                            document.getElementById('cities').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                        }
                    }

                    document.getElementById('location').value = place.formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    document.getElementById('lon').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

I retrive country name,
i retrive pincode 
i can also retrive location latitude and longitude
 but i can not retrive city 
Pleae Check this code and tell me what error in my code
 and i also wnat retrive district and state

Answer (score 0):

change cities for locality:

```
if (place.address_components[i].types[2] === 'locality')
```

Comment: you can accept the answer so the question is closed, and learn all the info you need here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches